# How to move directories that were listed in a .txt file?

Tags: command-line

I'm using a program to tag music that generates a `.txt` list of the skipped (untagged) folders that processes.

I just want to be able to take this list (that have the complete path for each folder) and move this listed folder somewhere `/media/skipped/`

I couldn't find with `du` command or `find` how to do it... And my capacities in CLI and in general with linux are very basics.

So thanks if someone can give me direction on my search, or some command to use...

Edit:

Ok... You are really awesome... thanks to all for your fast answers.
Yes each line is a path (actually have some line before each importing time, that i erase, and before the path says "skipped folder" that i run a Find and Replace command in mousepad. So, only paths, one per line rests)

Edit2: Solution from @Steeldriver worked. I just need to edit further the .txt. This post can be marked as [Solved], i don't know how to. Thanks to all.

Comment: Can you add an example of the text file list to your question.

Comment: @L.D.James, my file looks like this inside (after my edit taking out the unusefull part)

/media/txk/TrimarDieu/1_Zik/0_0zikt/Joseph Jazz/Thelonious Monk/Thelonious Monk The Complete Prestige Recordings - 2 
/media/txk/TrimarDieu/1_Zik/0_0zikt/Joseph Jazz/Thelonious Monk/Thelonious Monk The Complete Prestige Recordings - 3 
/media/txk/TrimarDieu/1_Zik/0_0zikt/Joseph Jazz/Toni Esposito - Gente Distratta 
**(In the preview looks all togheter, don't know how to copypaste different, but it is one path, one line)**

Comment: Caroxo, thanks for your interest to contribute back to the community by having your solved questions marked as solved.  This is something that only you can do.  It's easy.  Just look at the answer you're accepting and click on the check mark.  People with similar problems can see this exchange as resolved and have a better time of getting their solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest a *while loop*

```
while IFS= read -r dir; do
  echo mv -t /media/skipped/ "$dir" 
done < yourfile.txt
```

The `echo` is there so you can test the command - if it runs OK and lists out the correct sequence of moves, remove the word `echo` to make it run for real.

Example:

```
$ ls -l olddir/
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user 4096 Jul 27 12:32 subdir
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user 4096 Jul 27 12:32 subdir with spaces
```

with a list of files like

```
$ cat dirlist.txt 
olddir/subdir with spaces
olddir/subdir
```

then

```
$ while IFS= read -r dir; do mv -vt newdir/ "$dir"; done < dirlist.txt 
`olddir/subdir with spaces' -> `newdir/subdir with spaces'
`olddir/subdir' -> `newdir/subdir'
```

and verifying

```
$ ls -l newdir/
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user 4096 Jul 27 12:32 subdir
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user 4096 Jul 27 12:32 subdir with spaces
```

Comment: Nice, it listed ok, but have same problem when I take out the echo, it Doesn't recognize the spaces in the path.

Comment: Are you sure you remembered to put the double-quotes around the `"$dir"` variable?

Comment: Ok, sorry. Yes. It have worked. There was saying an error "Don't exist such directory", because it moved the first one and the subdirectories logically were not found. Your solution worked. Thanks a lot, and thanks also the others people suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a command like this:

```
while read line; do mv "$line" /media/skipped/; done < directory_list.txt
```

I am assuming that each line of the input file contains one directory entry.

Comment: Problem, the spaces in the paths are not recognized (and i cant edit each line for puting the \ before)

Comment: Sorry I just forgot to use quotes, fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

xargs is handy for this:

```
xargs -d '\n' mv -t /destination/dir < file.txt
```

Comment: The question asks about moving files, not deleting them. Please update and expand your post to answer the original question.

Comment: right, thanks. I was coming from a different question, so I wasn't that focussed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop like so:

```
for i in `cat file.txt`; do cp -r "$i" /media/skipped/" && rm -r "$i"; done
```

`file.txt` is the generated file, so you need to substitute the correct name.

Comment: This solution will not work if you have spaces in the directory names.

Comment: Thanks kraxor. Looks better now?

Comment: Not really. The problem is with the `for` loop itself, it will iterate through each *word*, not each *line*.

Comment: Actually I tryed (becouse i didn't read the comment of kraxor, and it doesn't do anything. Stays just with >, waiting and waiting. The other two options (yours @kraxor and Steeldriver ones) I had this problem with the spaces in the directory name. Thanks to all